# How can I show(read only) xslx, pdf files in react/javascript using (.xslx or .pdf) urls?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe, embed, docx

I can do it using all the google docs/sheets file shareable urls, but the link where url ends with .pdf or .xslx, it either downloads or is not able to be previewed.

This is the codesandbox link to experimentation.

[docs/xslx files preview codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vv7x86n3q5?fontsize=14)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use googles gview

see below,

```
https://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf
```